# Display images in template file

Tags: wordpress, image, templates

I have one template file for the main page, after creating home page I have added text to check if it reflect changes on my home page or not and it was successfully displaying text. But when I try to add image by clicking on add media option then image is uploaded but not displaying on my page. What piece of code should be used to get this image on my template file or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

i'am pretty sure u need to SETUP CHMOD to 744
because its randomly set to 600.
This means it is not public visible.

1.You just need to get an FTP Programm, 
2.Connect to your Webspace, 
3.Go to your Uploadfolder, 
4.Choose Your Image to Show with an RightClick, 
5.and set CHMOD to 744.

I'll show u here (FLASHFXP)
[image]
(Attribute set = READ)

I need to do this for every picture, so u will need to do it too.

Comment: but I am doing it locally on my wamp server

Answer (score 0):

Okay i didnt knowed that ;)

You can also try to set the file permissions via rightclick on the File in your Windows-System.
 
Like This:
 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j295p.png

make sure you have Admin-Privileges and the File is allowed to be read, change and execute, then it should work.

**There is another Option**
i recommend to Setup Wordpress to "DONT SORT UPLOADED FILES" to seperate folders like "per month", "per year" and this kind of Stuff, its better to have them Uploads all in ONE-Directory.(Thats my experience)

*In the past i also had my Problems with the Uploads, and it all occurred just because of the "Multiple Folder Uploads" that Wordpress makes.*

To change that go to: 
**Settings -> Media -> Sort Uploads by...**

*I recommend you to get a Free-Webspace for testing purposes, in my opinion its more comfortable to work online, and you can access it from everywhere you are :) Work never stops*

Answer (score 0):

you can add any custom field with this module https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/. And can easily add it to your pages and posts.